# Are strings defined as constants not NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c

I have a constant defined as:

```
#define BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING @"Importing Hands!";
```

But I get an error when I try to concat with:

```
NSString *updateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING, @" - Reading "];
```

This doesn't happen if I replace it with a string literal

```
NSString *updateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"foo", @" - Reading "];
```

Or a local string

```
NSString *temp = @"foo";
NSString *updateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", temp, @" - Reading "];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolon from your `#define`:

```
#define BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING @"Importing Hands!"
```

To the compiler, the resulting line looks like this:

```
NSString *updateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Importing Hands!";, @" - Reading "];
```

Comment: You've just repeat my answer =)

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
#define BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING @"Importing Hands!";
```

with

```
#define BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING @"Importing Hands!"
```

This is because compiler in your case replaces all occurrences of `BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING` with `@"Importing Hands!";`

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the accepted answer (remove semicolon), note that:

- `@"Foo"` *is* an NSString. You can even send it a message.
- `#define FOO @"Foo"` is a preprocessor macro, not a constant. It's a typing shortcut.

Though macros aren't an uncommon way to avoid retyping the same string, they're an unfortunate holdover. Essentially, they're playing games that aren't necessary anymore.

For repeated strings, I prefer:

```
static NSString *const Foo = @"Foo;
```

The `const` portion of this definition ensures that the pointer is locked down, so that `Foo` can't be made to point to a different object.

The `static` portion restricts the scope to the file. If you want to access it from other files, remove the `static` and add the following declaration to your header file:

```
extern NSString *const Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you be using

```
   NSLocalizedString(@"Importing Hands!", @"Message shown when importing of hands starts");
```

?

I put it as an answer because this looks like something you would not want to have to go and redo through all your code.